# Не пропускает кирилицу

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Вообщем не могу понять в чем дело, пропускает латиницу и цифры, а кириллицу не пропускает.

```
$filterinput = array(
  "TEXT"        =>  array("^[а-яА-Яa-zA-Z0-9_/]*$","только буквы и цифры")
);

return preg_match('~'. $filterinput[$type][0] .'~', $value);
```

Ошибок каких либо я не вижу, в чем может быть проблема не понимаю.

Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Модификатор /u в помощь!

Comment: Благодарю!